# CCAvenue Payment Page Redirect Error

Tags: magento-1.9, payment-methods, payment-gateway

From Today my CCAvenue asking extra details from customer like entering card details before going to CCAvenue Payment Page. Usually when customer select CCAvenue redirect to CCAvenue payment page then only asking card details, net banking, wallet, etc.

Screen shots :

Usually, CCAvenue Option like: https://snag.gy/9p2Wfq.jpg after
 click continue to redirect to the Payment page.

From Today it looks like: https://snag.gy/DTZ1bg.jpg Asking Card
 details. After entering card details, then will be open payment page, and
 again entering card details. Why getting this error. CCAvenue options label
 also not showing.

How can I solve this un relevant entering card details before redirect
 payment page?

Comment: If there is no change done by any admin option should not change if its suddenly asking for CC information on your site without making change is not good its looks like someone hacked and added code for collection card data check your site immediately. These things are not suddenly happens.

Comment: customer login not working,, is any issue?

Comment: This is working ccavenue : https://snag.gy/3GNrkR.jpg

Comment: this is error ccavenue : https://snag.gy/8mgxVf.jpg

Comment: post as an answer,  may be useful to others.

Answer (score 0):

If there is no changes done by any admin user, then any option should not change. If website suddenly started asking for Credit Card information on your website without making any change is not good, its looks like someone hacked your website and added code for collection of Credit Card data, check your site immediately, These things are not suddenly happens until changes are made.